# How to manipulate/clean the Linux Trash folder the pythonic way?

Tags: python, linux, recycle-bin

I know how the `Trash` folder in Linux is constructed.
So it wouldn't be that hard to manipulate it directly with some lowlevel filesystem commands.

I know the `trash-cli` package from Ubuntu GNU/Linux, too.

What would be a pythonic solution to clean the Trash folder on Linux without the two solutions above?

The background of my question:
I know that some file-managers don't use the `trash-cli` package programs. How do they do this? Is there a python package or a library (gtk, qt, ...) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trash folder" is not really a part of Linux itself. It is generally part of a desktop environment built on top of Linux.

Basically it is a [specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html) from freedesktop.org on how "trash can" implementations should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would check [`trashman`](https://trashman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [`autotrash`](http://www.logfish.net/pr/autotrash/), they are both based on python, so they can be imported in your script and invoked programmatically.